# Getting a message when name exists or added

Tags: php, mysql

I'am tryng to show a message after you pressed submit with information.

1. This name allready exists, use another
or
2. The name is added!

html

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required> 
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

php

```
$connectie=mysqli_connect("localhost","usernam","pw","db");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = stripslashes($name);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$check_if_exists="SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '$name'";

if($data[0] > 1) {
echo"already exists";
} else {

$newUser="INSERT INTO users (name) values('$name')";
    if (mysqli_query($connectie,$newUser))
    {
        echo "name is registerd";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error<br/>";
    }
```

Right now it post the echo on add.php, not on the page where the form is. How do I get it there?

Comment: You form sends it to add.php so it posts on add.php. It doesn't choose on its own. Leave it blank and move the code in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session / sessionflashdata.

First, you are not running the select query properly. It should have been:

```js
$check_if_exists="SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '$name'";

$count = mysql_num_rows($check_if_exists);
if($count != 0) { // this means that the name already exists:

 $_SESSION['msg']="The name already exists. Please try another name";
  

} else {
  
  //perform the insert query and have the session msg
   $_SESSION['msg']="The name was inserted successfully";
  
}
  
  header('Location: form.php');

// Now in your form page just above the form, have a div to display this message as:

<div class="msg"> 
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))

{
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
</div>

NOTE: you must start the session on both the pages. Have this code on top of both the pages

<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a session for this. Add `session_start()` to the top of both of your files.

```
if(mysqli_query($connectie, $uewUser))
{
    $_SESSION['flash'] = 'name is registered';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['flash'] = 'error<br/>';
}
```

Then in your page with the form, perform the following check wherever you want to print the data.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['flash']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['flash'];
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}
```

This will make sure that the  session message is preserved only for the next request.

Comment: Can I use this when I put a header(location) between the if else so it redirects directly back to the other page? Because I did try it and that didn't work.

Comment: @Kevin You can only modify `header` information if you've sent **nothing** previously. No echo, no print, no HTML, no data can be returned to the page prior to this. If you use this route, and there's no data being sent before, then you can safely use `header('Location: whatever');` and on the **page with the form** you can check use the code supplied in the 2nd block above.

Comment: like @Ohgodwhy said, you should not echo anything before the header('Location: whatever'); that is what has caused the error. And like you said about placing the header (location) code between if else, this should not matter too. Because, once the if code is executed, the whole else code will be neglected and the program execution handle will directly go to the header (location) anyway.